# Calling a telephone number to download Android/iPhone app

Tags: ios, installation, sms, phone-number

[Color App](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.color.android.socialcam&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5jb2xvci5hbmRyb2lkLnNvY2lhbGNhbSJd) for Android and iPhone can be downloaded by calling a certain number (call **COLOR (**26567)). **How exactly it works?** I'm interested in both the way it redirects the user on the UI level as well as the technology used.

I understand that "**" is some kind of special prefix used it US - **can it be done without this prefix (i.e. by calling an typical cellphone/stationary number)?**.

I am posting this question here because I believe it is related to programming. I also cannot check it as I live outside US.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer below is from the Developers website: http://support.color.com/home

I guess the computer-based answering machine records your number when you call it, and then sends out a text message with a direct link to the app. Quite simple and elegant solution.

---

### How do I get Color?

The easiest way is to call **COLOR (**26567) from your device. You will instantly receive a text message with a link to download the app from the Apple App store or Android Market.